# How can I remove a cell from a range for a property lookup array

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Lets say I have a value, A123456, in a column A, row 1, and i want to check if I have the same value in other rows of the same column, regardless of the length of the values as long as it has the same exact value I'm looking for. It may be DCBA123456, it should come out as true, since it has the A123456 in it.

Or on another note, how can I exclude, let's say, row 10111, from a range of rows 1-12000, all in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

One question at a time.

For the first one, try Countif() like this for a count of the value.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&A1&"*")
```

If you want to mark the rows where the value appears, try in B1 and copy down

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1,A7)),"found","")
```

[image]

For the other issue, please open a new question and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much, though I've already tried using countif, and it worked, 'til i realized that there are still same valued cells, with added units, which in I also like to mark. I have about 12k rows to check, and I can do it manually, but would take forever.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Edit your question and post a data sample. Manually mock up the desired result.